# Using behavioural modelling, how do I design a positive edge triggered T flip-flop with asynchronous preset and clear?

Tags: verilog, flipflop, modelsim

I am having trouble doing the above.
I have written a little bit of code along with a testbench, and it requires some changes. I also need to add the conditions for preset. How do I do that?

```
module t_flip_flop (clk,preset,clear,t,q);
   input t;
   input clk;
   input clear;
   input preset;
   output reg q;

   always @(posedge clk or posedge clear) begin
        if (clear)
            q <= 0;
        else if (t)
            q <= ~q;     
    end
endmodule

  module t_flip_flop_testbench;
  reg clk, pr, clr, d;
  wire q;

  t_flip_flop tff (clk, pr, clr, d, q);

  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    pr = 0;
    clr = 0;
    d = 0;
    #10
    clk = 1;
    #10
    clk = 0;
    pr = 1;
    d = 1;
    #10
    clk = 1;
    #10
    clk = 0;
    pr = 0;
    d = 0;
    #10
    clk = 1;
    #10
    clr = 1;
    #10
    clr = 0;
  end
endmodule
```

What to add for preset in the first module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `preset` signal to the sensitivity list, and you need to add another `else if` clause:

```
   always @(posedge clk or posedge clear or posedge preset) begin
        if (clear)
            q <= 0;
        else if (preset)
            q <= 1;
        else if (t)
            q <= ~q;     
    end
```

However, the [paper by Cummings, Mills and Golson](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf) points out a potential pitfall if the asynchronous clear and preset are allowed simultaneously.  Refer to section 5.2 *Modeling Verilog flip-flops with asynchronous reset and asynchronous set*.

Before you use this code, make sure that you really need both to be asynchronous.  It is more common to just have one of them to be asynchronous and the other to be synchronous.  For example, for asynchronous clear, the code would be:

```
   always @(posedge clk or posedge clear) begin
        if (clear)
            q <= 0;
        else if (preset)
            q <= 1;
        else if (t)
            q <= ~q;     
    end
```